# Some files under `/` are owned by UID `501`, is this dangerous?

Tags: security, uuid

I just noticed that that the directory `/usr` was owned by UID `501` on my system. Such a user does not exist on my system, as verified by looking at `/etc/passwd`.

Have I suffered a security breach, or is there some more normal reason for this to happen?

Comment: This can mean just anything.

Comment: @Christopher, Yes, I think that must be it. I remember a few weeks back I was trying to fix `flash` and unpacked a `tar` ball up there.

Comment: Please have a look at a spate of such questions over at SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/469070/recovering-from-a-system-wide-chown